# Highlight all the numbers in Cmd

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

How can I highlight the numbers in cmd? i.e, I want to highlight the numbers automatically when typing and in the old commands.

How can I achieve this?
I want to differentiate numbers from other commands in cmd to make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, CMD only supports a specified fixed foreground and background colour, which you can change using the COLOR command

```
Sets the default console foreground and background colors.

COLOR [attr]

  attr        Specifies color attribute of console output

Color attributes are specified by TWO hex digits -- the first
corresponds to the background; the second the foreground.  Each digit
can be any of the following values:

    0 = Black       8 = Gray
    1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
    2 = Green       A = Light Green
    3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
    4 = Red         C = Light Red
    5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
    6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
    7 = White       F = Bright White

If no argument is given, this command restores the color to what it was
when CMD.EXE started.  This value either comes from the current console
window, the /T command line switch or from the DefaultColor registry
value.

The COLOR command sets ERRORLEVEL to 1 if an attempt is made to execute
the COLOR command with a foreground and background color that are the
same.

Example: "COLOR fc" produces light red on bright white
```

You can't specify a different colour for different characters.

Comment: `iPython` also uses cmd but it highlights syntax.

Comment: I assumed a vanilla windows install, without some additional tools. Add it as an answer?